# PHP 6 - Roadmap?

Tags: php

Has anyone found a roadmap for PHP version 6?

Also, any very rough ETA on the release date (please don't answer "when it's ready", I'm just trying to get a sense of if it's first half of 2010, second half, etc)

Answer (score 2):

There already is a dev version that you can use, 6.0.0-dev

http://snaps.php.net/

If I had to guess, it will be 2 years at least before we see betas and release candidates.